# como acceder a un componente que esta otra carpeta en una carpeta en angular

Tags: angular, typescript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy tratando de acceder a un componente, pero el componente que quiero utilizar esta dentro de otra carpeta y mi pregunta es como acceder a un componente que esta en otra carpeta, ya intente  utilizando routerlink, básicamente lo que intente es esto:

```
import { InicioComponent } from './inicio/inicio.component';
import { UsuariosComponent } from './modulo1/usuarios/usuarios.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch:'full', redirectTo: 'inicio' },
  {path:"inicio", component: InicioComponent},
  { path: 'aboutus', component: ContactoComponent},
  { path: "insertarU", component: UsuariosComponent},

];
```

De lado de la barra de navegación para acceder a "inicio" y "aboutus" sí lo hace y lo hace muy bien pero para acceder a "insertarU" que es el componente que tengo en otra carpeta no me redireccionar a ese documento.

```
<a class="border-b-2 font-bold" routerLink="inicio">Main </a>
<a routerLink="aboutus">About us</a>
<a routerLink="insertarU">insertar</a>
```

Sí alguien pudiese ayudarme por favor

Comment: Pon la estructura de tus carpetas

Comment: @yussef ¿cómo hago eso?

Comment: Una foto que muestre el archivo del router y el UsuariosComponent, ya que al parecer tu problema está en la ruta que pones ahí './modulo1/usuarios/usuarios.component'

Comment: @Yussef compañero, ya subí la foto que me mandaste, la verdad borre la carpeta , estoy enfrentando un problema más grande. Sucede que  no redirecciona a ningún otro componente, este o no en otra carpeta y la verdad no entiendo porque.  Las rutas están bien. Como nota adicional, te comento que desactive el modo estricto cuando cree el proyecto lo que pasa es que necesitaba subir una imagen de php a angular y para poder usarlo tuve que deshabilitar ese modo porque de otra forma no funcionaba.

Comment: @Yussef y otra cosa yussef alguna vez has subido imágenes de angular a php , más que nada para ver si me pudieras ayudar con el código o en que parte de la documentación puedo encontrar esa información porque ya intente y intente y no la encuentro.

Comment: ¿Te aparece algún error en el navegador (incluyendo la consola de las fherramientas de desarrollador)?

Comment: Sería recomendable que las carpetas de tus componentes estén dentro de tu mismo proyecto, caso contrario puede generar conflictos. Mientras esté dentro de tu proyecto, puedes llamarlo normalmente. Nunca he probado llamando componentes fuera de mis proyectos de angular, pero no es muy recomendable.

Comment: Si lo borraste, puedes generar uno nuevo con `ng generate component modules/mi-carpeta/nombre-componente`. Recuerda siempre comenzar desde la carpeta modules, y posteriormente el nombre de tu carpeta / archivo.

Comment: @PabloLozano compañero pablo, que bueno que me dijiste lo de la consola, la verdad es que no me había dado cuenta que arroja este error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: This constructor was not compatible with Dependency Injection.
Error: This constructor was not compatible with Dependency Injection

Comment: Entonces el problema seguramente sea en el código del componente, no en el path de su fichero

Comment: @PabloLozano amigo, te agradezco muchísimo sí había un error, en el código de lado de mi servicio. Muchas gracias, ya lo resolví y también gracias a los demás a Cris22351 y a Yussef,